# Using a component of app module in a component of feature module

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

I was trying to refactor my angular source into multiple feature modules. Earlier the source had only one module and all the components were declared inside that single module. For refactoring, I did following steps:

1. Created a feature module
2. Moved a component from app module to feature module. Added the 
   component in feature module in declarations list and exports list.
3. Removed the references of the moved component from app module
4. Imported feature module into app module.

The source code compiles, but the site does not load. On the console, I could see it crashes because the component in feature module, on its html has used a component from app module.

[image: error on console]

I thought there is no extra step required to use a component from app module in a feature module. Am I missing something?

Added: 
Below HTML is from the moved component(component that I moved from app module to feature module), which is using app-organization-user-search component declared in app module.

```
<div class="col-md-12 full-width py-2">
        <app-organization-user-search (addClicked)="addParticipant($event)" (cancelClicked)="addingParticipants = false"></app-organization-user-search>
```

Added:
To all those who are searching answer to the specific problem, the solution is in the comments of the accepted answer.

Comment: Could you give us some example code from your module?

Comment: So newly moved component has the dependency in the app module? is that correct?

Comment: @Sudhakar, yes the moved component has a dependency on a component declared in app module

Comment: @DipenduPaul, Which is your root module? AppModule or future module? Are you importing the future module in App module?

Comment: can you restart cli ? and make sure name is correct for component and its selector

Comment: @Sudhakar app module is the root module and I have imported the feature module in app module.

Comment: @NiraliPatel I did an ng serve again, but it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For splitting one module into multiple ones, you should mind to export and import all modules and components correctly:

**app.module.ts** *the „root“ module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    // angular
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    // splitted modules
    DiversityMattersModule,
    PreventingAirPolutionModule,
    PeacfullyRevolutionModule,
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**diversity-matters.module.ts** *Example module from list above*

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    AwesomeComponent,
    // ...
  ],
  exports: [
    AwesomeComponent,
    // ...
  ],
})
```

Every component that depends on `AppComponent` is now allowed to import `AwesomeComponent`.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. I have imported the feature module into app module as suggested by you. I understood that a component of app module can use exported component of featured module. But can a component from feature module use a component from app module?

Comment: @DipenduPaul, No It can't use the component from app module. If you want then you can create a common module and import the common module to future module and app module.

Comment: Ok, that's an eye opener for me. I'll try your solution and mark it as answer. Thanks for the reply.